# Limits in Probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,...,X_n$ be a sequence of random variables which are defined
on the same sample space $\Omega$.

Show that limits in probability are unique almost surely. That is, if $X_n
 \rightarrow X$ almost surely and $X_n \rightarrow\bar X$ almost surely then $\Bbb P[X=\bar X]=1.$

I'm not exactly sure how to do this question as the limits are in probability. If anyone could tell me a way to prove it it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand if the question refers to limit in probability or limit almost surely. From your wording it seems the first one but when you clarify the question (after your "that is") you refer to pointwise convergence (which is different to convergence in probability). In any case the result hold with the weaker assumption of convergence in probability. You can proceed estimating the probability of $|X-\bar{X}|>\varepsilon$ and using triangular inequality.

Comment: I've edited it now to say almost surely

Comment: No, most probably the question should read: "Show that limits in probability are unique almost surely. That is, if $X_n\rightarrow X$ in probability and $X_n\rightarrow\bar X$ in probability then $\Bbb P[X=\bar X]=1$."

Answer (score 2):

Convergence in probability defines a topology on the space of random variables over $\Omega$. In particular, this topology is metrizable by the Ky Fan metric,

$$\rho(X,Y) = \inf\left\{\varepsilon>0: \mathbb P(|X-Y|>\varepsilon)\leqslant\varepsilon\right\}. $$

By definition, $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability iff $\lim_{n\to\infty}\rho(X_n,X)=0$. Since metrizable spaces are Hausdorff, limits are unique. Indeed, if $X_n\stackrel p\to X$ and $X_n\stackrel p\to\bar X$ then for any $\varepsilon>0$ we may choose $N$ such that $\rho(X_n,X)<\frac\varepsilon2$ and $\rho\left(X_n,\bar X\right)<\frac\varepsilon2$ for $n\geqslant N$, whence
$$\rho\left(X,\bar X\right)\leqslant \rho\left(X,X_N\right)+\rho\left(X_N,\bar X\right)<\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2=\varepsilon. $$ It follows that $X=\bar X$.